# Errors in sdl install and use in perl on windows

Tags: windows, perl, sdl, cpan

i have tried:

- in menu start: `CPAN Client`
- `install Alien::SDL SDL`
- i choose 64 bit and after a long while errors:
  [image]

what is wrong? it seems simple, but it's not

so i tried: `cpan -i --force SDL`

no errors, but i can't run Padre anymore :/
i try `perl name.pl` (with sdl code program) and it gives:

[image]

in 'cmd' in Windows 7: `cpan -i SDL` and it gives me (last part):

```
<pre>
t\sdlx_controller_interface.t ... ok
t\sdlx_fps.t .................... ok
t\sdlx_layermanager.t ........... ok
t\sdlx_music.t .................. ok
t\sdlx_rect.t ................... ok
t\sdlx_sfont.t .................. ok
t\sdlx_sound.t .................. ok
t\sdlx_sprite.t ................. ok
t\sdlx_sprite_animated.t ........ ok
t\sdlx_surface.t ................ ok
t\sdlx_text.t ................... ok
t\sdlx_validate.t ............... ok
t\smpeg.t ....................... skipped: smpeg support not compiled
t\ttf.t ......................... ok
t\ttf_font.t .................... ok

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t\core.t                      (Wstat: 0 Tests: 28 Failed: 0)
  TODO passed:   21-22
t\core_video.t                (Wstat: 768 Tests: 71 Failed: 0)
  TODO passed:   57, 59
  Non-zero exit status: 3
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
Files=59, Tests=3788, 188 wallclock secs ( 0.56 usr +  0.08 sys =  0.64 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/59 test programs. 0/3788 subtests failed.
  FROGGS/SDL-2.546.tar.gz
  E:\_win_7\Dwimperl\perl\bin\perl.exe ./Build test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports FROGGS/SDL-2.546.tar.gz
Running Build install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
```

So... i have tried "cpan -i SDL --force"

gives:

```
Test Summary Report
-------------------
t\core.t                      (Wstat: 0 Tests: 28 Failed: 0)
  TODO passed:   21-22
t\core_video.t                (Wstat: 768 Tests: 71 Failed: 0)
  TODO passed:   57, 59
  Non-zero exit status: 3
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
Files=59, Tests=3788, 147 wallclock secs ( 0.47 usr +  0.13 sys =  0.59 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/59 test programs. 0/3788 subtests failed.
  FROGGS/SDL-2.546.tar.gz
  E:\_win_7\Dwimperl\perl\bin\perl.exe ./Build test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports FROGGS/SDL-2.546.tar.gz
Running Build install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
Warning: Cannot install --force, don't know what it is.
Try the command

    i /--force/

to find objects with matching identifiers.
```

Answer (score -2):

So I tried:

```
cpan -i --force SDL
```

No errors, but I can't run Padre anymore. I tried

```
perl name.pl
```

(with sdl code program) and it gives:

[image]

Comment: I've edited this into the question: please delete this, as it its not an answer